# fcm firebase function undefined value - first attempt, defined - second attempt

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, firebase

I have an Android application and I intend to implement send notification through fcm. I have written below Javascript code for it but when I try to follow someone for the first time, the values are undefined, however, for the second time it works perfectly as expected...

[Undefined first attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOTTD.jpg)

[Defined second attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jo9db.jpg)

i tried nesting those three functions inside one, and also tried declaring variables locally but not solved.

```
"use-strict"
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();

var notificationDB;
var followedUserRef;
var followingUserRef;
var followingText;
var followingImageProfile;
var followedDToken_id;
var following;
var followingFullname;
exports.sendNotification =functions.database.ref("Notifications/{followed}/{notification_id}").onWrite((snapshot,context)=>{
    const followed = context.params.followed;
    const notification_id = context.params.notification_id;

    notificationDB = admin.database().ref(`Notifications/${followed}/${notification_id}`);
    console.log("Notification DB : "+notificationDB);
    notificationDB.on("value",(snapshotOne)=>{
        following = snapshotOne.val().userid;      
        followingText = snapshotOne.val().text;
    });

    followedUserRef = admin.database().ref(`Users/${followed}`);
    followedUserRef.on("value",(snapshot)=>{
        if(snapshot.val().token_id===null){
            followedDToken_id = "null";
        }else
        followedDToken_id = snapshot.val().token_id;   
    });

    followingUserRef = admin.database().ref(`Users/${following}`);
    followingUserRef.on("value",(snapshot)=>{
        followingFullname = snapshot.val().fullname;   
        followingImageProfile = snapshot.val().imageurl;   
    });

    console.log("Following: "+following);
    console.log("Followed: "+followed);
    console.log("followed user Ref: "+followedUserRef)
    console.log("NAME: "+followingFullname);
    console.log("FOLLOWING TEXT: "+followingText);
    console.log("tokken: "+followedDToken_id);
    console.log("IMAGE: "+followingImageProfile);
});
```

expected result should show on first attempt, but it fails at first and get the values at second time.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not entirely executed sequentially as you seem to expect, there are requests sent to the server and you need to do your console logs in the callbacks. For example here

```
notificationDB = admin.database().ref(`Notifications/${followed}/${notification_id}`);
console.log("Notification DB : "+notificationDB);
notificationDB.on("value",(snapshotOne)=>{
    following = snapshotOne.val().userid;      
    followingText = snapshotOne.val().text;
});
```

following will only be initialized upon response, which will be executed after you console log. So, you need to refactor your code with the following principles in mind:

- you initialize your variables
- afterwards you call the functions which send requests
- in the callback you do your console log

Even more elegant would be to use the Promise API.

Comment: i am really sorry but i didn't get what you mean. please explain with a sample code. idk javascript much, i just tried upto here.

Comment: that is not just logging them in console. it doesn't send notification in first attempt but sends in second

Comment: @Amanullah things like (snapshotOne)=>{/*...*/} are called arrow functions and in this case they are callbacks. Callbacks are not Javascript-specific, you can read about them if you search them. Now, it is entirely possible that the request was not responded upon the first "write". It would be great to see when the callbacks were executed against the time when the notification needs to be sent. It might be some unfinished business being the cause of the behavior you are talking about. https://codeburst.io/javascript-what-the-heck-is-a-callback-aba4da2deced

Comment: so in this case i used callbacks correctly, cuz until it didn't get the values initialized, its not going to be finished right ? then why after running this function values are not defined still. @Lajos Arpad

Comment: @Amanullah the values were initialized after the callbacks were executed. It seems that you intend to get the values before the callbacks were executed. Please try out the logging idea I have described in my previous comment.